# Validate multiple types in typeguard

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to validate multiple types inside a type guard? This is what I'm after:

```
interface A { }

interface B extends A {
  foo: number;
}

interface C extends A {
  bar: number;
}

function is<T extends A>(item: A): item is T {
  if((item as B).foo)
    // validate as B
  if((item as A).bar)
    // validate as A
}
```

This is how I intend to use it:

```
if(is<B>(item)) {
// do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, what you want is impossible.

The static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript code is compiled.  So this TypeScript code:

```
const item: A = { foo: 123 };
if (is<B>(item)) { console.log(item.foo.toFixed(2)); }
if (is<C>(item)) { console.log(item.bar.toFixed(2)); }
```

will likely compile to this JavaScript code:

```
const item: A = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { foo: 123 } : { bar: 456 };
if (is(item)) { console.log(item.foo.toFixed(2)); }
if (is(item)) { console.log(item.bar.toFixed(2)); }
```

At runtime, therefore, you need `is(item)` to somehow be a `B` check in one line and then be a `C` check on the next line.  The same call to the same function with the same parameter needs to return two different results... and not randomly, but based on type information which simply is not present.  The required functionality is supernatural, and beyond the capabilities of mere human-developed software.

---

If you want something which is possible to implement without magic, you need to pass your function information at runtime that it can use to determine what to check at runtime.  For example, perhaps `is()` should take a second parameter which is the name of the type you'd like to check for:

```
const item: A = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { foo: 123 } : { bar: 456 };
if (is(item, "B")) { console.log(item.foo.toFixed(2)); } 
if (is(item, "C")) { console.log(item.bar.toFixed(2)); }
```

Now it's at least conceivable that the implementation of `is()` can use this second parameter to figure out which property it should be checking.  And it turns out to be possible to implement and give an appropriately strong type signature, although it might be disappointing to see the elaborate contraption behind the magic trick:

```
type PossibleTypes = B | C;
const props = {
    B: "foo",
    C: "bar"
} as const
type Props = typeof props;

function is<K extends keyof Props>(
    item: A,
    typeName: K
): item is Extract<PossibleTypes, Record<Props[K], number>> {
    const key = props[typeName];
    return ((key in item) && (typeof (item as any)[key] === "number"));
}
```

Here we have given the compiler an explicit [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `PossibleTypes` that enumerates the possible types `is()` will check for.  Then, we make an object `props` that holds a mapping from type names `"B"` and `"C"` to the property name `"foo"` and `"bar"` that needs checking.  And the `Props` type is the type of `props`.

The `is()` function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`, the name of the type.  The return type of the function is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which guards if `item` is or is not a member of the appropriate type `B` or `C`.  The compiler determines this by [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)ing from the `PossibleTypes` union just the member which has a `number`-valued property at the key `Props[K]`.

The implementation of `is()` maps the type name to the key to be checked, and then makes sure that this key is in `item` and that the property at that key is a `number`.

---

There are undoubtedly other ways to modify your `is()` to a form which can be implemented, and I'm sure all of them are similarly dissatisfying in that you don't seem to be gaining any major advantage from putting these different checks in a single type guard function.  With only the types `B` and `C` it seems more straightforward to just give up and write this:

```
function isB(item: A): item is B {
    return ("foo" in item) && (typeof (item as any).foo === "number");
}
function isC(item: A): item is C {
    return ("bar" in item) && (typeof (item as any).bar === "number");
}
const item: A = Math.random() < 0.5 ? { foo: 123 } : { bar: 456 };
if (isB(item)) { console.log(item.foo.toFixed(2)); } 
if (isC(item)) { console.log(item.bar.toFixed(2)); }
```

But that depends on your use cases and temperament, I guess.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IL4CheiSyIoBCyEAHpCACYDOamuyryMA9hwFzIgCuAWwBG0ANy48BcNHhJkAYQrUIdRugws2wuFF4CR4yfhBxBEegAcSyAPIdLjTW3b8QCMMA4hkwegB4AFWUaBjQAPgAKYEhBXlQASl4YiEFfRmCsKAgwfigfeAAbeggxHHwXBG96MF9Y+OQAXmQAWTgwAAsAOig4Og5BSITkf2QABi6AVmQAfkx2Ll4ARgAmAGYcZF4sHT1kABZJgDYcCRdgGGRogNIolMEE4awqkHoOQoguwo4Ac2jYrqcDhdMAcABiwEoEFokRWjzKeHOl2u-gUd1ij3mLzeHy+v3+qS6uxB4Mh0Nh8PKUlM5isNgAChx6PRgMJgIUYgBPZhaVhgTmWFCM5msj6BAUWJrIcgAH0UZzY2NqligDkYzWcLjYpF4ACIgbqADS8rUKPW7XUm7DIOCMJUm-mC5D01WOKWOiAcS4qtUSE0wNweLw+Pz+ADSIVUYQA1hBOV7na76FETed6mhjVq2B6AHJmCC8MMmpJ1VLpZAAUWovQ8-mFLOEYol9ENyAAShAqlBaHWkwBtMMAXVbBlEUHC4WYWdYSuQse5zR9jj7ufzg4VWeyuXyV0i898IYxyAAZMerh6EwS0rabSBOQk+-PB01Gs1daPoLr4VaKorqrV7gaZo2k6Ho+loAYhhGcYplmeYgWWdZNm2ZBdl4Q4TmwDdfGRPwr1bXVSC-J5kGxd5Pm+P57kBLgSQhKEYThBIEWQAB6VjkFWNYujGMZkEEOBOVEE0LiuPD7gIhRiKxapyLxKiAWJUF6PJJiWPYg5jh4viBKEiB8GpfM6XkWwoAAcWAAA3CAAFVLCnNgA3cTxvHSUgr3iEt7nLchNU3HI8h8SJ9S4XUD1LB4TzPSIL1w2IbUYPp7xojgXzfD8oC-bDEUcwMXJDegFA8tAvPivxFAc-ztyC3ULXC+5hlPc8JUvbybyShIiV0NLkHfIQxyyn9Kn-CKgNadpul6fpBmGUYJmmOYsAQzikOtFC0M0zDsNE653IakiyNxSirxSuiyUYylrQ0rjtP4wThKRMTCqvTFnlko78WopTSQYilmM2DSMNu3ThIMoA)